# Issues interacting with elements when using PhantomJS and FluentAutomation.NET

Tags: dom, phantomjs, ui-testing, fluentautomation

I authored a couple of tests using SpecFlow, PhantomJS, Selenium and FluentAutomation.NET. They run fine on Chrome and FireFox, but when I run them on PhantomJS, they fail.

The error message is:

> element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

A search shows that this is usually caused by the element either being off screen, the page not being loaded fully or other random failures. Inserting a wait doesn't solve it and setting the `.With.WindowSize(1980, 1080)` doesn't work either.

The code is *very* straightforward, almost directly from the samples

```
I.Focus(SearchInput);
I.Scroll(SearchInput);
I.Enter(searchText).In(SearchInput);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting the `WindowWith` and `~Height` through the Settings object does wonders:

```
SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(
    SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.PhantomJs
);

FluentSettings.Current.WindowHeight = 1080;
FluentSettings.Current.WindowWidth = 1980;
```